# Why would I use Spark instead of Java to process data from cassandra?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

If I had to process 10 million records and search for a string match in one of the columns and I can do that easily with java.

What advantage would I have over java to do that in spark ?

Comment: For starters, Spark is distributed. If you only have one single-threaded Java or Spark node, then there is little to no difference.

Comment: thankyou. Why the down-votes ?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but Question is missing research effort, perhaps.

Comment: don't assume laziness, where it could be lack of comprehension. I did attempt to find out, waded through lots of docs, with minute details of how to do something but could not find the why. If you have links to share would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Assumptions are left to the reader. Feel free to [edit] your question with things you have referenced/tried

Comment: This was a straight-forward simple question, your answer was more than sufficient. I assume once I start using it, it will become abundantly clear. I have to say though the documentation that I have found is really scattered, deep in some ways but quite obscure in what it is intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can write a program in java and use its concurrency framework for making it parallel.

But, think for a while, for the example you mentioned, Cassandra APIs alone would be good enough!!! Why Java?

Cassandra is a reliable distributed data store. It provides some data processing capabilities but not flexible enough. So we think of using APIs exposed through other other programming language, eg - java.

Now, the question boils down to Java vs Spark? The simplest answer that I can thing of is, If you are sure a single JVM is enough for the processing requirements, go for Java else think about Spark or for that matter other distributed processing frameworks like flink etc.